# Python 3.3.5 Console does not start in PyCharm 2016.3.1

Tags: python, console, pycharm

Please, could you help? I am unable to get the python console started in PyCharm. Have played with all option available and have trawled through the documentation, but cannot figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated. Please find below the error I get in the console...

## OS: Win 10

```
C:\Miniconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 64331 64332
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 526, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: None
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 526, in <module>
    pydevconsole.start_server(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 355, in start_server
    interpreter = InterpreterInterface(host, client_port, threading.currentThread())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.interpreter = get_pydev_frontend(host, client_port, show_banner=show_banner)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 488, in get_pydev_frontend
    _PyDevFrontEndContainer._instance = _PyDevFrontEnd(show_banner=show_banner)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 318, in __init__
    self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\configurable.py", line 337, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 512, in __init__
    self.init_readline()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1911, in init_readline
    if self.readline_use:
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 554, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 532, in get
    % (self.name, obj))
traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: No default value found for None trait of <_pydev_bundle.pydev_ipython_console_011.PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x00000000042CFBA8>
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What code are you trying to run? Have you tried the simple `print("Hello world")`

Comment: Thanks, @MarkyPython ... I cannot run any code in Console... The IDE works fine though and I have configured to console to the same interpreter as the project...

Comment: I have not used Pycharm yet. It is good Software to learn python.But first check whether Python is installed or not in your system. Download a new version of python & use the inbuilt interpreter. Visit this link - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html This is the page of jetbrains and they are telling you to select the version. - I hope this would help you. If this answer finds helpful to you a Thumbs up. Happy Coding will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, I have already done this bit. Python is installed and works fine. The Console in PyCharm does not start - gives error as above. Console works fine with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: How are you running the code?  Try going to Run -> Run "[project name]"

Comment: @MarkyPython as I said before, IDE works fine. The Console does not work. The error message above is in the PyCharm Console Window....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much twiddling about:
Changing the interpreter to a different version (to Python 3.5.x) made this work. This made me wonder if IPython was the issue.. and it sure was!!

The problem is that the IPython for  Python 3.3.5 does not work with PyCharm. IPython Version 5 was installed by PyCharm, but does not work with Python 3.3.5.

I removed IPython using 'Conda uninstall' and then 'Conda clean' and restarted the console, it then worked like a charm...

In essence:
1. Exit Pycharm
2. Remove IPython - use 'Conda remove/uninstall' and then 'conda clean' to completely get rid of it.
3. Restart Pycharm and allow it reimport all 'skeletons'
4. Restart Console.

Comment: Great job of finding the solution and providing the answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Fedora 24. For some reason Fedora still ships IPython 3.x :/ I simply upgraded it with `pip3 install ipython --upgrade` which installed IPython 6.0.0 and it works :D